# Changing a logo&address when user changing a language

Tags: language, toggle, branding

What is best practices for changing a logo&address when user is changing a language of the site?

The site is now runing on sample.com/de
Now we starting with new brand on othersample.de

Any good idea?
M.

Answer (score 1):

Changing location based on language or vice versa, is not always a good idea.

Many countries around the world have multiple languages, often ones that originate from another country such as Canada where English and French are both widely spoken.

So setting an address to say Paris based on a user choosing French as the language, will work for users in France. However may confuse or annoy users in Canada.

This may not be an issue if you are only building local versions in one or two countries where languages do not overlap. however is something that could cause problems further down the line if you do expand to a country such as Austria where German is spoken.

**Brand side of things**

For the specific question about moving people between brands based on language, again I would feel it would be better to do this based on location.

Also the transition from one brand to another, when the user might have expected just the language to change, needs to be handled carefully. Perhaps explaining, "in Germany we are called Brand Y instead of Brand X, however you will get the same great service etc"

Answer (score 0):

I think the **smooth transition** between your switch will be a good idea and also some UI elements like loader will make it **noticeable**. I would suggest you refer [**Quikr.com**](http://www.quikr.com/). This website has no relation with language switch but still, this will be very helpful in your thought process.